# WPF application send parameters (MvvmLight with Page navigation)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, parameters, messenger

I have a WPF application with Page navigation. I use MvvmLight toolkit. I have two pages: `FirstPage` (default page) and `SecondPage`. On `FirstPage` I navigate to `SecondPage`.

I want to pass a parameter to `SecondPage`.

```
//code on FirstPage
NavigationService.NavigateTo(new Uri("SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
Messenger.Default.Send<string>("my mess");

//code on SecondPage
//constructor
public SecondPage()
{
  Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, GetMess);
}

private void GetMess(string obj)
{

}
```

When you first start it's not working. I can create an instance of SecondPage,

```
PageSecond page = new  PageSecond();
```

but it is not beautiful. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You are not following the MVVM principle with code like this in the code-behind. So following your start here is a simple (non-MVVM) way answer this:

Code on FirstPage -

```
        Page secondPage = new SecondPage("Hello");
        NavigationService.Navigate(secondPage);
```

Code on SecondPage

```
    // Public parameterless constructor - needed for designer
    public SecondPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Constructor with parameter 
    public SecondPage(string parameter)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyTextBox.Text = parameter;
    }
```

Comment: I need to implement with MVVM(Page, NavigationService ...) :(

Comment: I found  [this article](http://geoffwebbercross.blogspot.com/2012/04/mvvm-light-passing-params-to-target.html). It looks like my question but I do not understand solutions.